# Shortest way to code this php multiple if condition

Tags: php, if-statement

I am trying to do a query like:

If `$_GET['page'] == 'items'` AND `$_GET['action'] == 'new' OR 'edit'`

Here's what I have:

```
if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'items') {
    if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'new' || isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'edit') {

        // This is what Im looking for

    }
}
```

Is this correct, and is this the easiest way to make this query?

Comment: Well, it's a perfect valid way…

Comment: Yes, and any other developer will understand what your doing because your names are on point.

Comment: When you have more "OR" statements you could do it with a switch inside the first if statement.

Comment: @OP you already had the right solution in your own wording :) Your second line just needed brackets `()` at the right places and you could have pasted it straight into your code as for `php` `OR` and `AND` are synonyms for `||` and `&&` ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have done it like this as well:

```
if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'items') {
    if (isset($_GET['action']) && ($_GET['action'] == 'new' || $_GET['action'] == 'edit')) {

    }
}
```

Comment: This does not check for the page…

Comment: I meant it for the second if of course :) (I edited it, so it's more clear.)

Comment: +1 Correct `A && B || A && C` equals `A && (B || C)`. BTW the OP already had it in words :)

Comment: Id still suggest checking that both page and action are set before bothering to check what their values are.  As I said in my answer there is no point in checking the value of page if you then find out that action is not set.

Comment: @Jon Taylor Well, you could have a default action if none is given but a page is selected: Magento for example uses an action named "index" of none was given.

Comment: @feeela I agree however this is not what was asked in the question, in the question it suggests that both page and action must be set.

Answer (score 2):

Your way is perfectly fine, although I would almost be tempted to do it the following way.  The only reason I suggest this is that your code requires that both action and page are set.  If action is not set then there isn't much point checking if the page is == 'items'.

```
if(isset($_GET['page']) && isset($_GET['action'])) {
    if($_GET['page'] == 'items' && ($_GET['action'] == 'new' || $_GET['action'] == 'edit')) {
        //do code here
     }
}
```

Comment: You can do `isset($_GET['page'], $_GET['action'])` in one shot as well ;)

Comment: Ah you learn something new everyday, I did not realise this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may also try `in_array` like:

```
if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'items')
{
    if ( !empty( $_GET['action'] ) && in_array( $_GET['action'], array( 'new', 'edit' ) )
    {
        // This is what Im looking for
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is one of possible solutions

```
if ( @$_GET['page'] == 'items' && in_array(@$_GET['action'], array('new','edit')))
```

Comment: Im not sure I would encourage this, although it will work it could produce errors later on.  @ just supresses errors and so rather than error handling you are just ignoring (which in my experience is bad).

Comment: I used it just to shorten the code. And yes, using @ is not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is ok, but also you can use function:

```
function paramIs($param, $values) {
    $result = false;
    foreach ((array)$values as $value) {
        $result = $result || isset($_GET[$param]) && $_GET[$param] == $value;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Usage:

```
if (paramIs('page', 'items') && paramIs('action', array('new', 'edit')))
{
    // your code here
}
```

It will reduce the number of repetitions in your code and encapsulate logic in one place